# Long import in Elastic search, use aliases?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have this very long running elastic search import, which needs to be completely new (removing all previous entries). I can't do that on the live index because then my site would be down for those hours.

Is using aliases a solution for this or are there other better solutions?

Comment: If you have disk space, yes, index into a new index and when you are done change the alias definition to point to the freshly indexed data instead of the old index.

Comment: thanks, will be finding out if I have enough diskspace I guess ;-)

Comment: I'd say you need to establish this beforehand, not to run into surprises ;-) even with the old index.

Comment: true, but this is  in progress, have never done a full index yet so no idea of diskspace usage so far